# How to get google plus page ID using API

Tags: php, api, google-plus

I am facing problem for getting multiple google+ page ID using googleplus API.

I Get a person's profile using php code.

```
$me = $plus->people->get('me');
```

output:

```
{
"kind": "plus#person",
"etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
"emails": [
{
"value": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
"type": "account"
}
],
"urls": [
{
"value": "https://plus.google.com/b/112141871367245409492/112141871367245409492/",
"type": "contributor",
"label": "Finite Infotech"
}
],
```

In this output i got the google+ page url

```
https://plus.google.com/b/112141871367245409492/112141871367245409492/
```

I have created two different pages on my google plus account but output shows only one google plus page url . I need two get all google plus pages url using api.

How to get other page url or page id using google plus api?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$me = $plus->people->get('me');` will only ever return a single person/page at a time. `me` is a shortcut meaning the currently authenticated account, which in your example is one of the pages. In order for `$me = $plus->people->get('me');` to work for your other page, change the authentication to it.

Comment: OK thanks for the response.

Is there any google+ api to provide google+ page id? I need to get google+ page ID.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @abraham how do I get a particular activity for a specific business page I created? I am only authorized for my main account using `me` scope. Do I  have to authorize on the behalf of that page again? I only want do `$activity = $plus->activities->get($activity_id);` but for activity id belongs to one of the business page & not may main account.